# SpringFramework integration test Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I write this integration test but now i do not know how to fix this **IllegalStateException** which is about that the application context can not be load. **LoginControllerTest2-context.xml** is in the same package with tested controller.

**ControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:LoginControllerTest2-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("login.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest2 {

    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:login;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASS = "";
    private static final String SCHEMA_FILE = "h2.sql";
    private static final String DATASET = "login.xml";

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Resource
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createSchema() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource().getConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(LoginControllerTest2.class.getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FILE));
            RunScript.execute(conn, in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void loadTestData() throws Exception {
        // mockMvc =
        // MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("classpath:LoginControllerTest2-context.xml").build();

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(wac).build();

        // mockMvc =
        // MockMvcBuilders.annotationConfigSetup(LoginControllerTest2.class).build();

        IDataSet ids = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(LoginControllerTest2.class.getResourceAsStream(DATASET));
        JdbcDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL, USER, PASS);
        databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(org.dbunit.operation.DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
        databaseTester.setDataSet(ids);
        databaseTester.onSetup();
    }

    private static DataSource dataSource() {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUser(USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASS);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
    public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("../../WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("passportId", nullValue())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
    }

}
```

**StackTrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from ServletContext resource [/test/loginController/h2.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/test/loginController/h2.sql]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from ServletContext resource [/test/loginController/h2.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/test/loginController/h2.sql]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:437)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:229)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CompositeDatabasePopulator.populate(CompositeDatabasePopulator.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.execute(DataSourceInitializer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/test/loginController/h2.sql]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:138)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:274)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:434)
    ... 48 more
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.loginController" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> -->

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
                <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
                <property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:h2:mem:login;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4" />
                <property name="username" value="sa" />
                <property name="password" value="" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="/test/loginController/h2.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

Comment: See here: `Could  not open ServletContext resource [/test/loginController/h2.sql]`

Comment: @Jens I saw that but the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are attempting to lookup `/test/loginController/h2.sql` from the ServletContext.

I'm not familiar with MockMvc but I'd guess that you need to tell it where your test web root is so that `ServletContext.getResource(...)` can find the file.

Comment: I have edited my question. In xml file i have specified where h2.sql is but and the path is correct. I suppose that getResourceAsStream() have to find it.

Comment: I have no idea why it's trying to access from ServletContext. You should try `location="classpath:/test/loginController/h2.sql`. Also, make sure that h2.sql is under `src/test/resources`